# I want to add class to parent menu when clicked on sub menu

Tags: jquery, css, angular

I write a bellow code for my functionality

HTML::

```
<ul class="parentUL">
    <li>
      <a class="parentMenu">
        <span>Parent Menu</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li>
          <a (click)="addClass(submenu.url)">Sub Menu 1</a>
        </li>
         <li>
          <a (click)="addClass(submenu.url)">Sub Menu 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

CSS Class ::

```
.active{
  color:red;
}
```

Ts File Function ::

```
addClass(url){

  // For add the class to parent menu
  $(this).closest(".parentUL").find('a:first').addClass('active');

  // For the another functionality

   this.router.navigateByUrl(url);

}
```

I want to add `.active` class on function click. Its not adding class for me.

Comment: from where are you getting `this` ?  Pass that here i.e : `(click)= addClass(this)` .Also ,then in js change `addClass(el){` and `$(el).closest(".parentUL")....`

Comment: if you are using angular then why you are sugin jquery to add classes you can simply do that using `ngClass`

Comment: please refer the updated code.   i dont want to use ngClass. i want to add class when i am calling this addClass function

Answer (score 0):

When you call the function from the click event, jquery don't know what `this` refers to. so you have to tell it.

```
onclick="addClass(this)"

function addClass(obj) {
  $(obj).closest(".parentUL").find('a:first').addClass('active');
}
```

**Demo**

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="parentUL">
  <li>
    <a class="parentMenu">
      <span>Parent Menu</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>
        <a onclick="addClass(this)">Sub Menu 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a onclick="addClass(this)">Sub Menu 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<script>
  function addClass(obj) {
    $(obj).closest(".parentUL").find('a:first').addClass('active');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: but i am already passing the url parameter with function for another functionality, so how i can pass the parameter for Jquery class add.  or any other way i can do this? like with ngOnInit() or else?

Comment: @SamK Can't you not just do `addClass(submenu.url, this)` and `addClass(url,obj){`